# How to increase space allocated for linux

Tags: partition

I am using Linux mint and at the time of installation I allocated 2GB space for file root of Linux. Now I need more space for Linux I tried to do it via gparted. But I can't figure out how to do it. 
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Right now you cannot extend your `/dev/sda8` partition because you have free (unallocated) space niether before nor after it. So, firstly you need to either
shrink `/dev/sda9` releasing some space at **beginning** of `/dev/sda9`
or
shrink `/dev/sda7` releasing some space at **end** of `/dev/sda7` and merge it with `unallocated` partition between `/dev/sda7` and `/dev/sda8`
Then you will able to resize your `/dev/sda8` partition and aquire unallocated space